# Take number from previous record within interval of missing days (BigQuery)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to insert records into an output table for the missing days. Best explained through example:

Input_table

[image]

output_table

[image]

That will allow me to capture on_hand_stock for any given day, warehouse_id, sku combination.

I need a date record for each day between the first created date per warehouse_id/sku and the current date. The filler records should capture the on_hand_stock value in the preceding record.

While I could do something like:

```
SELECT 
*,
CASE WHEN last_value(current_on_hand ignore nulls) over (partition by sku, warehouse_id order by reated ASC) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
last_value(current_on_hand ignore nulls) over (partition by sku, warehouse_id order by created_at ASC) END AS on_hand_2
FROM 
input_table
```

I am unsure how to insert the 'filler' days in my output_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select day as created, warehouse_id, sku, on_hand_stock
from (
  select *, 
    lead(created, 1, current_date + 1) over(partition by warehouse_id, sku order by created) - 1 next_date
  from `project.dataset.table`
), unnest(generate_date_array(created, next_date)) day
# order by created desc
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]